# XAML code behind x:name property is unaccessable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to xamarin forms, I created an Android Forms apps. But when i give x:Name="" to any element in xaml. In code behind i can't access this property id.
- I updated nuget packages even i keep trying to rebuild projects. But still unable to access xaml ids in code behind. I also uninstalled and installed visual studio multiple times. But still the same problem.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: If it's a question of getting red squiggly lines under the names, saying that the element can't be found, that's a bug in Visual Studio. Do you get errors at compile time or only in the editor?

Comment: No, There are not any build or rebuild errors. Only problem is i can't access the xaml ids' in code behind. And emulator works fine.

Comment: It's a strange issue. Could you provide your project?

Comment: facing the same issue has anyone found the solution? its weird x:Name is not accessible in code behind on Xamarin form development.

Comment: There are lot of people facing this issue why this guy given downvotes? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25409/problem-with-xaml-x-name-and-access-from-code-behind

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the project once after adding control in the Xaml.Then you will be able to access the control.

Comment: I build the project many times. But still unable to access in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this code and find what is wrong in your code:
**TestPage.xaml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   x:Class="TestImageCropping.TestPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Text="Hello"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Text="Xamarin"/>
     </ContentPage.Content>
   </ContentPage>
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestImageCropping
{
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.TextColor = Color.Blue;
        button1.Text = "Click here";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap your label and button in a container for your example to work...

Comment: InitializeComponent();
            Slider.Value = 0.5;
            label1.TextColor = Color.Blue;
            button1.Text = "Click here";

Comment: I used this code. But still error is same. not able to access x:name code behind

Answer (score -1):

There are some issues related to x:Name property and accessing it in background...
Try to write it manually, it will work.